# database in iphone apps

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I am new to iphone development. I am currently doing a restaurant app which takes data from a database. How can we store the data in a DB on iphone through our app so that it would even work offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **SQLite**. Since the database is just a file, you can add the 50 MB file to your application, and that's it. SQLite's performance on the iPhone is good, in my experience, although YMMV depending on your exact table layout and indexes.

Just remember to keep a keen eye on how much data you fill it with:

Although 50 MB is way below the limit, be aware that a 50 MB application will take some time to download for people, and people cannot install it from the AppStore without either a WiFi connection or iTunes.

Also, applications that "grow" in size too rapidly after you install them can become unpopular on the smaller devices.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)

Comment: Thank you Nils,could you please elaborate by some example or a bit in more detail...how to use SQLite in my app?

Comment: @Nils: I thought normally we should use CoreData?! (Sorry, I don't much about this area, and it is a genuine question)

Comment: @Anthony : You can use CoreData, if you'd like. But I see a stronger tendency of using SQLite, and it has a sligthly stronger structure IMO.

Comment: @dinny : added a tutorial to my answer.

Comment: yep, i didnt find much materials on this and i really have no idea

Comment: @Nils - in your opinion why do you think that SQLite has a stronger structure? Personally I like using CoreData but I am genuinely interested in hearing about this.

Comment: @sosborn : watch the memory allocations performed on rudimentary tasks with both systems. Theres simply too much jitter with CoreData, plus i saw Apple iOS dev team switching from CoreData to SQLite themselves in the official apps (mail, messages and contacts) and that to me is a clear indicator.

Comment: @Nils - Yeah, I mean, that is to be expected since it is an ORM. For a high volume application you are probably correct to suggest SQLite.

Comment: If you wanna take it out in the chat, I'd gladly defend my statements ;] No need to draw lengthly discussions in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQLite is your best bet.  Apple uses SQLite a lot in iOS 'internally' (DB for text messages.etc), so Apple must've put a lot of effort into optimising SQLite on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For Restaurant app, you can also use plist as a database. This is because you will only have a primitive datatypes and will be easy to handle with plist.